# Can’t get my 3-way Lutron lights set up properly. Toggle switch still keeps lights off

Tags: wiring, lighting

The original toggle switch –if turned off – prevents the Lutron Caseta side from turning on, so I assumed I wired it incorrectly.

I’ve attached my wiring on both sides and [the instructions](https://www.casetawireless.com/Documents/0301710a_Caseta%20Advanced%20Inst.pdf) (see page 33-35 for my model).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRC9Q.jpg

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like the first switch is a standard toggle, **not** a 3-way. I suspect you have panel->toggle switch->Caseta->lights, in which case nothing will work if that toggle switch is off.

Comment: I don't see any wire tags on your photos, so it looks like you did not follow the instructions as NEC 110.3(B) requires.   3-way switch wiring is heinously confusing *on a good day*, so failing to mark stuff is inviting fiasco.  It would have been better to capture that information *before* removing the old 3-ways... but it can probably be recovered -- any 3-way wiring will have 2 travelers (both in the same cable). The wires to 3-ways are 2 travelers and 1 non-traveler... the non-traveler is what they wanted you to tag.

Comment: Can you post photos looking into the back of the box the Caseta was installed into?

Comment: Yeah I should have tagged it. I can try to do it now once I figure this out. @ThreePhaseEel - here’s the back https://imgur.com/a/Hvp0PnH

Comment: @getrichordiediying -- can you get us another angle of what's in back that shows us which cable the red wire is connected to?

Comment: Sorry for late reply here. Turns out there’s no way to make it work without switching the other switch out with a Lutron as well – called Lutron to confirm. That’s why they make the Pico switches. Thanks for everyone’s help.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I can’t actually get this to happen with the standard switch on the other side. Called Lutron and they confirmed I do need a Lutron switch or Pico remote installed on the other 3-way. Thanks for everyone’s help!

Answer (score 0):

### Swap the connections to the black and blue wires

Your problem is that you have the switch wired in line with the incoming always-hot (black), instead of the signal/sense wire (blue).  Swapping the connections to the black and blue wires on the Caseta will fix the issue.

Comment: Are you sure?  I see the red wire on Caseta going to a red wire from the wall (which must surely be a traveler).  Noting the schematic I just linked, the red wire is supposed to go to *the load*.